# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_BaseScan_CycleCount_Report]
@StartDate varchar(10),
@EndDate varchar(10)

AS

BEGIN

    IF @StartDate AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.CycleCountHistory
        WHERE RecordDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
        
    ELSE 
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.CycleCountHistory
END
```

> Error message: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
> usp_BaseScan_CycleCount_Report, Line 16 An expression of non-boolean
> type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_BaseScan_CycleCount_Report,
> Line 21 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
IF @StartDate AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL
```

You're expecting this to be evaluated as:

```
IF (@StartDate AND @EndDate) IS NOT NULL
```

But the way SQL Server evaluates it is:

```
IF (@StartDate) AND (@EndDate IS NOT NULL)
```

So the error is that `@StartDate` is not a boolean expression, and cannot be used as part of the `IF` expression.

Instead, you'll need to do something like:

```
IF @StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL
```